# How to Change Cassandra Commitlog of Existing Nodes

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have been working with Cassandra, and I am not happy with the read latency. I am building a data warehouse using Cassandra, and my BI tool takes a a lot of time to read 5M records. After searching about the issue, I found out the it is not recommended to have the commitlogs and the data on the same disk. So my question is, how can I change the commitlogs location?

Just to let you know, I have a 4 Cassandra nodes on one data center with one seed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's right. You can change the location address of commit logs and data in Cassandra.Yaml file at /etc/Cassandra/conf/Cassandra.Yaml

You have to repeat this change at all your 4 nodes.

References:
Initialization properties
http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html

Good luck!